# struts2 Createcriteria

Tags: hibernate

I have parent/child relationship with Activities/Favorites now i want to display from parent table where company not equal to 'xyz' and child table where company equal to 'xyz'

i.e A jsp is displayed with all records where parent company is not equal to 'xyz'(which is users companyid who logged in) and with checkbox from child table. when user selects checkbox it stores the parentid, the users company id and checkbox value which is true in child table.

so there is a possibliyt one acitivy might have more than one child record with same parentid and diffrent company name.

Could any one please help me how to acheive in hibernate. I have tried using
    session.createQuery("from Activities where upper(COMPANY)<>'" + userCompany +"' and accNominated='true'").list();

but it is dispalying parent record and all the child records with that parentid. But i want to display parent records and all the child records with same activityid and ifferent companies which are checked  but not respective to company who logged in.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without grammar your question is a little hard to follow, but it sounds like you are wanting to select Favorites with certain criteria, that are linked to Activities with certain criteria.

```
List<Favorite> favorites = session.createQuery(
        "from Favorite f " +
            "inner join f.activity a " + //assuming Favorite.getActivity() exists
        "where f.companyId <> :currentCompanyId " +
            "and a.companyId <> :currentCompnayId " +
            "and ... " +
            "and ...")
    .setParameter("currentCompanyId", companyId)
    .list();
```

This will return `Favorite`s associated with `Activity`s where neither has a certain `companyId`, along with any other criteria you want to place on either records.

Comment: Sorry for my grammar. Actuall i was all the child records with a compnayid and also parent records different company id. ie. a jsp will display all the records not belong to his company and he can select them and that gets stored with his company id. So next time when displayed it should the already selected ones and all the records from the he does not belong.    I tried writing something like this but is get an " from  Activities a   left outer join Favorites f where f.company = 'TABS' and a.company <> 'TABS' and a.accnominated='true' and a.activityid=f.activityid"; Error:

Comment: DEBUG [http-8080-Processor22] (ErrorCounter.java91) - throwQueryException() : no errors
DEBUG [http-8080-Processor22] (HqlSqlBaseWalker.java111) - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
DEBUG [http-8080-Processor22] (FromElement.java129) - FromClause{level=1} :  com.tai.domain.Activities (a) -> activities0_
ERROR [http-8080-Processor22] (ErrorCounter.java56) -  Path expected for join!
DEBUG [http-8080-Processor22] (ErrorCounter.java51) -  Path expected for join!